# Check Who is the chat room owner?

Tags: discussion, chat

recently i just request to join a private chat room. I got this below message.

[image]

But i want to see who is the main owner of this Chat?

Do i have privileges to check who is the owner? Just kind of my info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the *info* link to go to the room info page:

[image: room info link highlighted]

Room owners are listed on that page, and that information is public to all:

[image: Owners header on info page highlighted]

Comment: I got it. But here i show there are more then 1 owners are available.So this all owners ,right?

Comment: Yes, a room can have multiple owners, and each of those can nominate you to talk.

Comment: @MD: did you see the labels above the sections? That right section lists users *currently in the room* or *frequently in the room*. That's a *separate list altogether*.

Comment: @MP Ok thanx and sorry for Bother you on this.